# How can I position an anchor that will be shown exactly between a fixed header and footer?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a site where the content lies under a fixed header and footer and you can navigate through anchors and only the active anchor is shown, the rest is hidden under the footer and header (like window).
I positioned the content, header and the footer 
but i dont know how to set the anchors so that the content of the clicked anchor will appear in the right spot which should be exact between the header and the footer.

*hope somebody can understand what i want do*

**CSS and html only** dont want to use jquery or js

---

example:
edit: http://cdpn.io/olvhq

Comment: your pastebin is useless without html, you better do a codepen or jsfiddle to see your code in action.:)

Comment: To answer the `ip` link question:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131639/are-ip-address-links-valid-in-posts

Comment: used codepen now thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try:

```
#anchor {    
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `box-sizing` property.

Like so:

**[FIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/11/)**  **[FIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/10/)**

```
.container
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -64px 0;
    padding: 64px 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
header
{
    height: 64px;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
footer
{
    height: 64px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```